# How to create Filter for org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have to create Filter for my CheckboxTreeViewer. I'm not getting how to do that. I'm using following class

```
org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.shared.FilteredCheckboxTree
```

and following way to get the FilteredCheckboxTree object:

```
FilteredTree ft = new FilteredCheckboxTree(parent, null, 0, null);
```

but it is telling me:

The constructor FilteredCheckboxTree(Composite, FormToolkit, int, PatternFilter) refers to the missing type FormToolkit.

I'm not getting what exactly the problem is. Please help if you know about it. Or if there is any other way to get Filter then do let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a dependency on `org.eclipse.ui.forms` (which contains `FormToolkit`) to your plug-in.
2. Much better, to avoid dependency on internal packages, use `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree` and override `doCreateTreeViewer`.

Comment: From FilterdTree, I'm getting the TreeViewer, but I need CheckboxTreeViewer. What's the way to get that?

Comment: `CheckboxTreeViewer` extends `TreeViewer`, so you can return one from `doCreateTreeViewer`.